# add square of all items in a column as a row in R data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe as shown below containing 3 rows or n rows more generally. I want to add a 4'th row or n+1'th row containing sum of squares of all items of that column.

```
x<-data.frame("a" = c(2,3,4),"b" =c(3,4,5))
> x
  a b
1 2 3
2 3 4
3 4 5
```

In the above example, the 4'th row should contain value of 29 and 50 respectively.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An option is

```
library(dplyr)
x %>% 
   summarise_all(~ sum(.^2)) %>%
   bind_rows(x, .)
#.  a  b
#1  2  3
#2  3  4
#3  4  5
#4 29 50
```

---

Or in `base R`

```
rbind(x, colSums(x^2))
```